# SCons does not find header files when using variant_dir

Tags: scons

Hello I running a problem with the use of relative paths and changes in the variant_dir
I have a hierarchical SCons construction. From a main SConstruct I'm calling sub SConcripts representing the layers of
my project:

```
mcal_build_dir              = os.path.join(env.subst('$OUTPUT_DIR'), 'objs', 'MCAL')
infra_build_dir             = os.path.join(env.subst('$OUTPUT_DIR'), 'objs', 'INFRA')

mcal_path             = os.path.join('../../Targets/TC275/MCAL/SConscript')
infra_path            = os.path.join('../../INFRA/SConscript')


mcal_objs = SConscript(mcal_path, exports='env env_base', variant_dir=mcal_build_dir, duplicate=0)
infra_objs = SConscript(infra_path, exports='env env_base', variant_dir=infra_build_dir, duplicate=0)
```

inside the INFRA/Sconscript

```
includes = [
  '../MCAL/api',
  ........
  ........
]
# SOURCE FILES
sources = [
    'src/ECU_StartupTask.c',
  ....
]
for include in includes:
    own_env.Append(CPPPATH=[Dir(include).abspath])
```

When it compiles it the header files in MCAL/api are found:

```
gcc ....... -fno-peephole2 -D_GNU_C_TRICORE_=1 -Ioutput\objs\MCAL\api -IC:\Repositories\fcm3_ssb_sk\Targets\TC275\MCAL\api -Ioutput\objs\ASW\swc_PyroControl\code\api .....
```

now I need to have 2 different build flavours for the mcal, so I tried to perform 2 compilations of the same code in a
different build dir

```
mcal_build_dir              = os.path.join(env.subst('$OUTPUT_DIR'), 'objs', 'MCAL/hw_3x')
mcal_build_dir2                 = os.path.join(env.subst('$OUTPUT_DIR'), 'objs', 'MCAL/hw_4x')

The point is that only changing this the INFRA SConscript does not compile, the headers MCAL/api are not found. 

gcc ....... -fno-peephole2 -D_GNU_C_TRICORE_=1 -Ioutput\objs\MCAL\api -Ioutput\objs\ASW\swc_PyroControl\code\api .....
```

""" note that the absolute path to the MCAL\api is not added in the compilation line """

So it seems that for some reason the absolute path to -IC:\Repositories\fcm3_ssb_sk\Targets\TC275\MCAL\api is not found.
I don't understand the relation of  the INFRA/SConstruct with the mcal_build_dir change. Is not suppose to be
independent? I mean when I build the INFRA layer I'm using includes as relative paths to the INFRA/SConscript. 
I think that when you change the build_dir the SConscript directory is *copied* to the build_dir and compiled there, but
what about the header files out of the INFRA layer itself? are they copied? how does the INFRA/SConscript know the
absolute path to MCAL/api the first time and not the second time.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't address your main issue, but you have a lot of incorrect SCons usage which I'm commenting on and showing a better way here.

Wow some confusing code here: See comments

```
# No need to use env.subst or os.path.join here.
mcal_build_dir              = os.path.join(env.subst('$OUTPUT_DIR'), 'objs', 'MCAL')
infra_build_dir             = os.path.join(env.subst('$OUTPUT_DIR'), 'objs', 'INFRA')
# should be 
mcal_build_dir              = '$OUTPUT_DIR/objs/MCAL'
infra_build_dir             = '$OUTPUT_DIR/objs/INFRA'

# These os.path.join's do nothing
mcal_path             = os.path.join('../../Targets/TC275/MCAL/SConscript')
infra_path            = os.path.join('../../INFRA/SConscript')
# So change to this
mcal_path             = '../../Targets/TC275/MCAL/SConscript'
infra_path            = '../../INFRA/SConscript'

# don't see any issues with this so far..
mcal_objs = SConscript(mcal_path, exports='env env_base', variant_dir=mcal_build_dir, duplicate=0)
infra_objs = SConscript(infra_path, exports='env env_base', variant_dir=infra_build_dir, duplicate=0)
```

From your INFRA/Sconscript

```
includes = [
  '../MCAL/api',
  ........
  ........
]
# SOURCE FILES
sources = [
    'src/ECU_StartupTask.c',
  ....
]

# This does nothing (adding via Dir().abspath does not cause SCons to use absolute paths.
for include in includes:
    own_env.Append(CPPPATH=[Dir(include).abspath])

# So do this instead
own_env.Append(CPPPATH=includes)
```

Next bit of code sample which has issues:

```
# The subst and os.path.join once again isn't needed.
mcal_build_dir              = os.path.join(env.subst('$OUTPUT_DIR'), 'objs', 'MCAL/hw_3x')
mcal_build_dir2             = os.path.join(env.subst('$OUTPUT_DIR'), 'objs', 'MCAL/hw_4x')
# Do this instead (no need to pre-substitute and SCons will convert the /'s to \'s if necessary
mcal_build_dir              = '$OUTPUT_DIR/objs/MCAL/hw_3x'
mcal_build_dir2             = '$OUTPUT_DIR/objs/MCAL/hw_4x'
```

All file/directory references are relative to the directory the SConstruct or SConscript resides in (And/or the variant_dir)

I notice that you use ../.. as the starting path many places. Why not locate your SConstruct there? It would make for a much more typical layout/SConstruct location.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, actually this is a big inherited project from another company that builded the initial skeleton. I'm trying to adapt this to a _multitarget_ _builder_ project_

Comment: @AlbertoRiera come over to the scons discourse channel and ask for help/advice. Also have you read the users manual. Big section on variant dirs. https://discord.gg/bXVpWAy